# is there a way to open websockets in Tridion

Tags: javascript

I am a frontend developer I dont have knowledge of tridion SDL.

Is there any way to open websocket using SDL Tridion.

I want to add fuctionality like this http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/smartphone-remote-control-for-presentations/  in a site which is based on tridion.

Is it possible in tridion ?

Comment: Assuming you're joining a team where there is already an implementation, you should probably check how code is currently deployed, and your implementation should follow those principles. In some cases people publish code from Tridion, in most cases nowadays code gets deployed using other tools - just make sure you find this out, then use everything you need. Tridion does not stop you from using anything, including websockets, but your architecture/infrastructure may.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, but read the long answer.

Long answer: Unlike some CMS solutions, Tridion does not serve your website, it provides various means of publishing content, which your web application can then consume through one of its Content Delivery APIs. This means that your web application can use whatever technologies you wish, as long as you can communicate with one of the APIs to retrieve the content (there are options for .Net and Java plus an OData Web Service).